\NewDocumentCommand with TikZ calc library
recently I was doing a lot of various diagrams and found myself experimenting with the \newcommand to define labels and "variables". As such I wanted to expand and experiment with commands that compute something but I'm simply stuck.
I have a command \pos defined, and when I "dump" it, it seems to create correct "text", but when placed inside tikz it is not working. I think that I'm not escaping something correcly, but experiments with noescape rendered no usable results.
Am I of the base here and something is hindering the calc parser and as such is impractical to implement? Or is it something else I'm missing?
PS: Following command seems to work, but I wanted more universal approach:
\newcommand{\betweenX}[2]{($(#1.west)!#2!(#1.east)$)}
\newcommand{\betweenXside}[3]{($(#1.#2 west)!#3!(#1.#2 east)$)}

EDIT: this also works:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xparse}

% Define a macro using \NewDocumentCommand
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyMacro}{mm}{%
    ($(#1)!0.5!(#2)$) % Calculate the midpoint between #1 and #2
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Define nodes A and B
    \node (a) at (0,0) {A};
    \node (b) at (0,-2) {B};
    
    % Now you can directly use the macro to calculate the midpoint and place a node there
    \node at \MyMacro{a}{b} {Midpoint};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Current Code:
\documentclass[margin=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}
\NewDocumentCommand{\pos}{ m o m m o }{%
\def\dir{#1}%
\def\anchor{#2}%
\def\point{#3}%
\def\range{#4}%
\IfNoValueTF{#5}{\def\pointTwo{\point}}{\def\pointTwo{#5}}%
\IfStrEq{\dir}{x}{%
\def\dirLeft{west}%
\def\dirRight{east}%
}{%
\def\dirLeft{south}%
\def\dirRight{north}%
}%
\IfNoValueTF{#2}{%Determine the anchors if provided
\def\anchorLeft{}%
\def\anchorRight{}%
}{%
\def\anchorLeft{\space\anchor}%
\def\anchorRight{\space\anchor}%
}% Calculate the position
(\point.\dirRight\anchorRight)!\range!(\pointTwo.\dirLeft\anchorLeft)%
}%
\newcommand{\mydump}[1]{(\${#1}\$)}

\begin{document}

% Example usage
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    cell/.style={draw, minimum width=5em, minimum height=10em},
]
    \node (A) at (0,0) [cell] {};
    \node (B) at (0,-5) [cell] {};
    
    \node (C) at ($ (A.south)!.5!(B.north) $) [draw] {node to place programmatically};
    %\node (C) at {\pos{x}{A}{.5}[B]} [draw] {node to place programmatically}; % <-- how to make it work?
    
    \node (DEBUG) [draw, right = of C] { \mydump{\pos{y}{A}{.5}[B]} };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Inside a tikzpicture, PGF does its own parsing and it needs to see certain things. In particular, on a path, it searches for the next thing it needs and, if it doesn't find something suitable, it fails. So the \def etc. are not being read as definitions at all. I think the parser is basically skipping over those looking for one of the things it expects to see. You'd need the command to be expanded before the parser sees it - so before the \node (C) at is read, I guess. But I'm not sure why the first case works. I can say that you're fighting the tide here. Use pgfkeys methods instead.

The most important rule for any commands for use inside a TikZ path is: it needs to be fully expandable.
Regardless of your actual definition, your m o m m o command is not and won't be with \NewExpandableDocumentCommand since it doesn't end with a mandatory argument.
We can do a m o m o m work, though:
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand*\tikzposxl{west}
\newcommand*\tikzposxr{east}
\newcommand*\tikzposyl{south}
\newcommand*\tikzposyr{north}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\pos}{ m o m o m }{%
                       ($(#3.\UseName{tikzpos#1r}\IfNoValueF{#2}{ #2})!#5%
  !(\IfNoValueTF{#4}{#3}{#4}.\UseName{tikzpos#1l}\IfNoValueF{#2}{ #2})$)%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (0,-2) {B};

\node (C) at \pos{x}{A}[B]{.5} {new node};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

If you only want this for the at part of a node, you'll be okay.
For other coordinate specification in a path, this won't work. And unfortunately, TikZ's calc parser would make alternative approaches problematic again.
If you can't make an expandable version, in your special case where you only use that coordinate to specify the at part of a node/pic/coordinate, you can actually make this a key that uses the at key at the end:
\NewDocumentCommand{\pos}{ m o m m o }{%
  % anything you want
  \tikzset{at={<your result>}}%
}
\tikzset{my pos key/.code={\pos#1}}

And then you can use \node[my pos key={{x}{A}{.5}[B]}] {};. (The optional argment [B] needs to be protected with braces from the node's parser.)

For more versatile options, the best you can do is a custom coordinate system, where your argument can be anything. You just need to set \pgf@x and \pgf@y to communicate the coordinate to PGF/TikZ. This needs a few internal macros though as can seen below.
I'd argue for a key-value argument here, though which can just as complex as your command, it just has speaking argument names instead of a random collection of optional and mandatory arguments.
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\makeatletter
\tikzdeclarecoordinatesystem{my pos}{%
  % do whatever with #1,
  % just set \pgf@x and \pgf@y at the end
  \pos#1%
  \expandafter\tikz@scan@one@point
  \expandafter\pgfutil@firstofone
  \expandafter(\tikzpospoint)%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand*\tikzposxl{west}
\newcommand*\tikzposxr{east}
\newcommand*\tikzposyl{south}
\newcommand*\tikzposyr{north}
\NewDocumentCommand{\pos}{ m o m m o }{%
  \edef\tikzpospoint{%
                          $(#3.\UseName{tikzpos#1r}\IfNoValueF{#2}{ #2})!#4%
    !(\IfNoValueTF{#5}{#3}{#5}.\UseName{tikzpos#1l}\IfNoValueF{#2}{ #2})$%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node (B) at (0,-2) {B};

\node (C) at (my pos cs:{x}{A}{.5}[B]) {new node};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

